# Why the 2d array treatment in PHP isn't good?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build a 2d array in PHP with two loops using two different queries.
for some reason the page is not showing any message about any error that occurred.
It just reacts like the array doesn't exist.

Therefore I am assuming its because I did't handle the array right.

This is the code:

```
$stuarr= array();        ***//the 2d array initialization***

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE userid= '$uid' ORDER BY name"; 
$stulist = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die ("cannot query the table1 " .mysqli_error($conn)); 
while ($students = mysqli_fetch_array($stulist)) {
    ${$students['name']}= array();   ******//the inside array initialization...the one that will insert to $stuarr***

    $count=$_SESSION['counter'];
    $sname=$students['name'];
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE userid= '$uid' AND rankers='$sname' ORDER BY therate DESC"; 
    $stur = mysqli_query($conn,$query3) or die ("cannot query the table1 " .mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($sturank = mysqli_fetch_array($stur) && !$count==0) {

        array_push(${$students['name']},$sturank['rated']);
        $count=$count-1;
        print_r(${$students['name']});
    }

    array_push($stuarr,${$stulist['name']});
    print_r($stuarr);  ***///this print is showing nothing***
}
```

I would love to hear your opinion about the code.

thank you!

Comment: Why would you use variable variables like that? Just do `$student = array();`, put the data into it, and finish with `$stuarr[] = $student;`...

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what `${$students['name']}` is actually doing.

Comment: @PatrickQ well how good of you to explain it, then.

Comment: $students['name'] is a field from a query, and I want to initiate a new var for each name...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
array_push($stuarr,${$stulist['name']});
```

into

```
array_push($stuarr,${$students['name']});
```

Comment: why is this a solution, please explain.

Comment: thank you, it's working but not as I expected... it printed: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) )        it insert o,1,2 values and not the real one